# Why does PDO for Postgres return integer for an boolean field

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I trie to copy data from one DB to another. Both have 100% identical structure.

When I fetch a row via PDO I get integers 0/1 instead of native false/true for boolean fields. This is a problem when I trie to insert the data into the second DB using PDO leading to this error message:

```
column "disabled" is of type boolean but expression is of type integer
```

Is there an easy way out? An option I am not aware of? Because I am talking about hundreds of different boolean fields here. Casting them individually is out of the question. If there is no easy way I will have to read the column types and act on this. But I wounder why PDO behaves this way.

Im using Postgres 9.0.1 and PHP 5.5.6

**Additional Info:**

Here are some relevent code fragments. Sorry the code is too complex to show it all. **It works for all fields but boolean**:

```
        $db = new PDO(
                "pgsql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$name",
                $user,
                $pass,
                array(
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => $persistent,
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                )
        );
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ...' 

        $sth = $db->query($sql);

        $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName (".implode(', ',$cols).") VALUES (:".implode(', :', $cols).")";

        $sthInsert = $dbInsert->prepare($sql);

        foreach ($row as $k=>&$v) {
            $sthInsert->bindParam($k, $v);
        }

        $sthInsert->execute();
```

Comment: can you please provide your code

Comment: I wonder if PDO returns bools as integers because most DBs don't support BOOL column types.  MSSQL, MySQL, and Oracle are some I know offhand that don't.  (Making this more confusing is that Oracle's PL/SQL language supports BOOLs even though its tables don't.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the retrieval of the column which is not handling booleans correctly, but the subsequent binding of the value.

You can check this by doing a simple select:

```
$result = $db->query('Select true as test_truth, false as test_falsehood;');
foreach ( $x as $row ) { var_dump($row); }
/*
array(2) {
  ["test_truth"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["test_falsehood"]=>
  bool(false)
}
*/
```

The problem is that when binding the variable in the subsequent prepared query, PDO is coercing it to a string, because the default value for `$data_type` in `PDOStatement::bindParam` is `PDO::PARAM_STR` ([as documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)).

`(string)true` is `'1'` and `(string)false` is `''`. These are then being passed to the Postgres connection, which cannot convert them back to boolean, giving the error.

The workaround therefore doesn't need any metadata about the expected type of the data, only the actual type of the value being passed in. One approach would be this:

```
 if ( is_bool($value) ) {
     $value = ( $value ? 't' : 'f' );
 }
 $statement->bindParam($k, $value);
```

This effectively creates an alternative cast to string, using `'t'` and `'f'`, which are Postgres's default representation of `true` and `false`, respectively.

Alternatively, you could set the parameter type based on the PHP variable type:

```
switch ( gettype($param) ) {
     case 'boolean':
          $param_type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
     break;
     // other cases here as necessary
     // see http://php.net/gettype and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php
     default:
          $param_type = PDO_PARAM_STR;
     break;
}
$statement->bindParam($k, $param, $param_type);
```

Comment: Confirmed to work! Thanks for the insight. I still wounder if this could be concidered a bug on PDO or if this is unavoidable.

Comment: @Torge I've updated the answer with a reference to the manual which explains why this happens, and an alternative approach to solving it.

Answer (score 2):

Not answering your question but proposing a more straightforward way of doing it and avoiding the `PHP` transit by doing it all in `SQL`:

```
insert into t (col1, col2)
select a, b
from dblink('dbname=the_other_db', 'select a, b from t') as t_other(a integer, b boolean)
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html

If there is some processing that is done in `PHP` that you don't know how to do in `SQL` ask about it in another question.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to map IDs on the way, as the target already has entries with these IDs. Also its from one DB to another not from one table to another.

Comment: @Torge About different DBs use `dblink` as in my updated answer. About mapping `IDs` may be you could explain it.

Comment: dblink looks interesting, I will take a look at it for the sake of learning. About the ID mapping.
I have to move one set of customer data from one DB to another. Something not really planned for in the past. There are clashes of primary keys. So the transferred entries get new IDs and I have to update this new IDs in several other tables where they are refferenced.So I need to process this in PHP.

Comment: @Torge I have been doing [`ETL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) in SQL for many years so it is definitely possible but if it is a only once operation and what you are comfortable with is PHP then I guess it can be more productive.

Comment: It would be really tricky as even some IDs are referrenced in strings (4,7,9). But I guess you are right. However safety goes first here and so I use PHP also to create an extensive log file of the operations for later... Anyway, thanx for the dblink hint. this will be usefull in the future, one upvote from me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems this is the quickest way. It works, but I consider this a bug until someone can explain me why this needs to be done:

```
$sql = "SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '$tableName'";

$typeRows = DBH::fetchAll($sql);

foreach ($typeRows as &$tr) {
     $columnTypes[$tr['column_name']] = $tr['data_type'];
} unset($tr);

...

switch ($columnTypes[$k]) {
    case 'boolean' :
         $v = $v==1;
         $sthInsert->bindParam($k, $v, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
         break;
    default :
         $sthInsert->bindParam($k, $v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an array `$cols` I don't know what that is but I have proposed a solution below for how to define it if you don't want to get the information from the database as proposed in another answer.  In addition I also think you need to add `:` to your `bindParam` key values.

```
$cols = array('col1' => 's', 'col2' => 'b');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName (".implode(', ',array_keys($cols)).") VALUES (:".implode(', :', array_keys($cols)).")";

    $sthInsert = $dbInsert->prepare($sql);

    foreach ($row as $k=>&$v) {
        switch($cols[$k]){
            // null
            case 'n':
                $sthInsert->bindParam(':' . $k, $v, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
                break;
            // bool
            case 'b':
                $sthInsert->bindParam(':' . $k, $v, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
                break;
            // int
            case 'i':
                $sthInsert->bindParam(':' . $k, $v, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                break;
            // str
            case 's':
                $sthInsert->bindParam(':' . $k, $v, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                break;
            // lob
            case 'l':
                $sthInsert->bindParam(':' . $k, $v, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
                break;
            default:
                $sthInsert->bindParam(':' . $k, $v);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: $cols only holds the column names. And I get it by $cols = array_keys($row);